# Roslyn CodeFix can't find previously created AdditionalDocument

Tags: c#, file, code-analysis, roslyn

I am writing a C# Roslyn Analyzer & CodeFix which will create a new `.txt` file, based on some variables, if it doesn't exist and it will append a new line if it does.
The Analyzer and the creation of the file work perfectly using the following code in `RegisterCodeFix` Action:

```
var proj = document.Project.AddAdditionalDocument("file.txt",
            "text content");
return proj.Solution;
```

Although, when I am trying to search the project's collection `AdditionalDocuments` it is empty, even if the file is created previously (and the project is saved, if that matters).

```
var doc = document.Project.AdditionalDocuments.FirstOrDefault(x =>
 x.Name == "file.txt"); //doc is null
```

I tried adding the new file as a plain `Document` instead of an `AdditionalDocument` but the `file.txt` is created as a source code file `file.cs` and not as a `.txt` one, but, for a reason, I can find it as `file.cs` in the `Project.Documents` collection.

Any thoughts of how can I create a non-source code file in a `CodeFixProvider` and use it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the changes to your `workspace` after you've added the document:

`workspace.TryApplyChanges(proj.Solution);`

However, according to [this link](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4425), it seems that a current bug means `AddAdditionalDocument()` doesn't persist the document beyond the `workspace` in memory, meaning the project will not have the new document when reloaded.

Also, `AddDocument()` will only add documents with an extension corresponding to the language of the containing project, for instance, calling `AddDocument()` on on a C# Class Library project, will rename the extension to '.cs' if not already so.

Comment: Nope, `TryApplyChanges` doesn't fix it, otherwise, it creates new files when I hover the CodeFix option with the mouse.
If I am saving the project with the new file, closing it and opening it again, the file is there, so I don't know, maybe this issue is somewhat fixed?
Finally, yes I tried `AddDocument` too with no luck.